# Why clojure function is not working or crashing in core.cljs [reagent]?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I have a function `encode` that takes a seed and message to return a cipher.

My issue is that when I tried to use it in my core.cljs file with reagent, the function is silently failing (returning an empty string).

I feel like I'm doing something (or approach) wrong so any quick pointers will be highly appreciated.

```
(prn (encode "testing" "test"))           ;;> ""
(prn (type encode))                       ;;> #object[Function]
(prn (type (encode "testing" "jordan")))  ;;> #object[String]
```

For example I was expecting: "mikmbry" from `(encode "testing" "test")`. Everything works on the repl but silently fails on `core.cljs`.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you please share implementation of your `encode` function?

Comment: Sure here it is: [gist](https://gist.github.com/mohamedhayibor/45423dfe60c51a8f22a80ab056726541).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has an issue with handling Strings in ClojureScript.

JavaScript doesn't have character type and ClojureScript doesn't introduce its own type. Instead when you treat a string as a sequence, it's individual elements will be one-character long strings:

```
(seq "ABC")
;; => ("A" "B" "C")
```

If you need to get the ASCII number value of a character you need to use JavaScript's `String.charCodeAt(index)`:

```
(.charCodeAt "A" 0)
;; => 65
```

To convert a number (as ASCII code) into a string you can use `String.fromCharCode`:

```
(js/String.fromCharCode 65)
;; => "A"
```